# Swagger/Swashbuckle showing "Unknown response type"

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, openapi

I am creating an C# ASP.NET Core 2.0 REST API, all going well for the most part.  It is using MVC routing to gen the REST API.  The controllers are pretty simple.

```
    // POST: api/Volume/{zoneID}/Set/{volume}
    [HttpPost("{zoneId:int}/[action]/{volume:int}", Name = "Set")]
    public IActionResult Set(int zoneId, int volume)
    {
        return CreateAndSend(strZonesLevel, zoneId, $"{volume:X2}");

    }
```

Using the latest of everything, installed Swagger/Swashbuckle for AspNetCore 2.3.0 and the UI comes up with the APIs and all.  The SwashBuckle UI works well, I can test the API etc.

The one exception is that on the UI, the Response type ALWAYS comes back as "Unknown Response Type."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qqBh.jpg

I have the following attributes in front of my class (all methods return the same type)

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Volume")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ControllerResponseModel), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ControllerResponseModel), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ControllerResponseModel), 500)]
```

The generated JSON seems allright, the ControllerResponseModel is in the definition, and referenced in all the right places by the Volume API.  Here is a subset.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "AVController API"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/Volume/{zoneId}/Set/{volume}": {
      "post": {
        "tags": ["Volume"],
        "operationId": "ApiVolumeByZoneIdSetByVolumePost",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": ["application/json"],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "zoneId",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          {
            "name": "volume",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ControllerResponseModel" }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ControllerResponseModel" }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Server Error",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ControllerResponseModel" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ControllerResponseModel": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "command": { "type": "string" },
        "message": { "type": "string" },
        "url": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why the UI would not be showing the return type and value?  I have tried numerous things, like using gets instead of posts as well as using the [SwaggerResponse] attributes, but the results are the same.

Comment: I'd suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues) in the Swagger UI repository on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next stop.  Will do.

Comment: Turns out this is an Edge browser issue with Swagger/Swashbuckle.  It works fine in Chrome/FF.  The Swashbuckle team is investigating.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as an Edge browser issue with Swashbuckle, not the code posted here.  It is reproducible on many sites.  Issue has posted on GitHub @ https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4337